# Bootstrap centered responsive vertical navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having some trouble achieving the style I would like for my responsive bootstrap navbar.

I'm pretty new to bootstrap/css and jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YfmwV/ is what i've hacked together so far.

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner"> <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Showtime</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Motivation</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is related to the following code which achieves what I am after in the large screen view however completely ruins the menu in responsive mode.

```
.navbar .nav>li {
    width: 12.5%;
}
```

I am trying to get the navbar items to take up the whole space of the navbar as opposed to being aligned either left or right, the only way I could think to do this was to set the width to a percentage, this is not ideal.

If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be amazing.

Comment: I'm confused. You want the `li` to be `width:100%` without having to actually declare it? Just don't declare anything. Block elements by default take 100% of parent's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a **@media** query so that your width:12.5% is only applied for desktop mode..

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 979px) {
    .navbar .nav>li {
        width: 12.5%;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://www.bootply.com/wauacskYQj

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally understanding what you mean, but for as far as I can understand, you want to have the hover and active effect to not have any padding/margin on either sides.

Navbar-inner has a padding left and right of 20px, if you set those on 0, the bar is taking the full width of your menu.

```
.navbar-inner {
padding-right: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}
```

Is this what you mean?